# ios read z_pk from sqlite coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, key

if I use a sqlite browser [mozilla addon] to check the sqlite generated by coredata in my simulator, I see that coredata creates a unique key called `Z_PK`
how can I read this key?

thanks a lot!

Comment: A word of warning: Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't read that key. If you are using Core Data with SQLite, you should not access the database file directly. The Core Data table schema is not documented and could change without warning (and has done so in the past). If you ever have a situation where you think you need to access the SQLite store backing up Core Data then you are pretty much guaranteed to be doing something severely wrong and trying to fix it by doing things that are even more wrong. What are you doing that you believe getting at this data would be useful or helpful in some way?