# Z_PK Column in Core Data Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to fetch the number from the Z_PK column created by Core Data?  If so, would you fetch this column the same way you would fetch attributes you created manually in the model?

Comment: why do you need the _primary key_? `CoreData` builds the accessors very well, working with the _primary keys_ are not a usual practice with `CoreData`.

Comment: I just need a unique id to reference each entity.  Was just curious if using the primary key was better than creating my own unique attribute.  Based on Kevin's answer, I am just going to create my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sqlite to directly access the columns created by CoreData.

However, you shouldn't depend on Z_PK or any of the columns to stay consistent. The schema could change (and has) between releases. Apple has stated this in WWDC videos.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  That is a very good point. I've seen some of the WWDC Core Data videos, but didn't remember this.

Answer (score 6):

The z_pk is not an attribute that you can fetch like any other the other attributes. What you can do is to extract the z_pk value from the `managedObjectID`of your entity

The managedObjectID can be obtained using `[self objectID]`. For this example we take this one:

```
   <x-coredata://03C5C895-3245-4D0F-8B6B-7758582AE16B/<your-Entity>/p5>
```

The `p5`  at the end is the z_pk. (For this store, and for this entity, at at this time. It can change)

Not sure what you need the z_pk for, nor in what format. Let's convert the `managedObjectID` into a string:

```
   NSString *aString = [[[self objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
```

From the string extract the `5`:

```
   NSArray *theComponents = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/p"];
   NSInteger theZpk = [[theComponents lastObject] intValue];
```

Now you have the z_pk as an `int` and can process it as you like.

Comment: Thanks Olaf.  I've decided to go a different route since the z_pk may change.

Answer (score 0):

[ios read z_pk from sqlite coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577848/ios-read-z-pk-from-sqlite-coredata)

See this link to know more. As I know, we can't fetch Z-PK from core data. But you can know it by saving core data file like sqlite file and you can check it by query.